# when hour = 12,it parses to 00, why?

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

When I'm going to get a long with `new Date().getTime()`, I find that when time > 11:59:59, it always resolve 00:xx:xx, for example; 12:00:00 --> 00:00:00, 12:23:56 --> 00:23:56;

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date parse = null;
try {
    parse = format.parse(str);
    log.debug("time{}", parse);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

when `str = "2022-01-12 11:59:59"` it works well;
when `str = "2022-01-12 12:00:00"` it works badly, it gives me 00:00:00;
when `str = "2022-01-12 12:15:00"` it works badly,it give me 00:15:00;
when `str = "2022-01-12 13:15:00"` it works well,it give me 13:00:00;

Comment: because at midnight, a new day begins

Comment: You're parsing your date as 1-12 hour string and printing it as 0-23 hour string. What did you expect. 12 AM == 00 in 24 hour format.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` - why are you still using?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for SimpleDateFormat,

> h ==  Hour in am/pm (1-12)

So 12pm is midnight.

If you want a 24hrs time, upper case 'H' rather than lower case 'h' to represent hour

> H ==  Hour in day (0-23)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-01-12 12:15:00".replace( " " , "T" ) )
```

## Details

As others said, your formatting pattern is incorrect in its use of `hh` for 12-hour clock rather than `HH` for 24-hour clock.

Furthermore, you are using terrible legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Your input strings nearly comply with the ISO 8601 standard for date-time strings. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2022-01-12 12:15:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime`. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

i got it,it should be hh:mm:ss ---> HH:mm:ss